# INSERT Statement after a SELECT in mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to execute two SQL statements in one mysql_query.

```
$mySql = mysql_query("SELECT itemid, points FROM items WHERE id='1' UPDATE accounts SET userpoints = '1000'");
```

Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only execute one query in `mysql_query` (even if you seperate the queries with the semicolon terminator).

You have to call them seperately (although [this guy](http://www.dev-explorer.com/articles/multiple-mysql-queries) has a method to automate that).

Comment: Also, the WHERE is missing in the UPDATE query.

Answer (score 2):

If you use mysqli you can use [`mysqli_multi_query()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php)

Comment: A better solution - if you're using PHP5 take advantage of MySQLi!

Comment: Be carefull with that though, MySQLi is **even more susceptible to SQL injections**, because it allows this kind of code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/xkcd-sql-injection-please-explain

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't try doing that since you won't be able to exploit the results from the different queries (returned values, mysql_insert_id(), ...)